# How set miminum height for split PdfPCell

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, tabular

On page I have table, and at the end of the page I have one paragraph, if rows contains small count of rows paragraph must still stay at the end of the page, but if rows too much and table take more than one page paragraph must be just after the table end. At first it looks easy for me and I just set minimum height for PdfPCell which contains table, but then I discover if page is split on pages minimum height apply to each part of table, and because of it paragraph isn't under the table on second page. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one not very good solution for this problem, I've added one column to the table, which width it too small and it isn't visible for users, in this column I've add table with two rows, for first row I set minimum height which I need, here the code for creating this additional column

```
private PdfPCell createMinHeight(float minH) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    table.setHeaderRows(0);
    PdfPCell firstRow = new PdfPCell();
    firstRow.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    firstRow.setMinimumHeight(minH);
    firstRow.setPadding(0);
    table.addCell(firstRow);
    table.addCell("");
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.addElement(table);
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you don't want the paragraph splits? You can use `setKeepTogether(boolean);` for the elements you need:

```
paragraph.setKeepTogether(true);
```

or

```
table.setKeepTogether(true);
```

Comment: paragraph isn't matter, I want minimum height doesn't apply to second part of split PdfPCell.

Comment: I found one not very good solution for this problem, so don't bother about it.

Comment: even if it's not really polite, post it as answer to help others ;)